# How to make a link clickable in React.Js inside render?

Tags: html, reactjs, render

How to make a link clickable in React.Js inside render? If I click the link it goes to home page. I want to follow the link only. 
my code looks like this

```
              <tr>
                <td>IPFS Hash # stored on Eth Contract</td>

                <td><a href= "#">{"https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/"+this.state.ipfsHash}</a></td>
              </tr>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope that I understood your question, I think what you are looking for is

```
  <tr>
     <td>IPFS Hash # stored on Eth Contract</td>
     <td><a href={"https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/"+this.state.ipfsHash}>Click here to go to home page</a></td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 9):

The React way to add a click and redirect is to use the Link to provided by the react-router-

Inside the component

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom;
class Parent extends React.Component{
    render(){
         <div><Link to="/home">Click here to go back to home page</Link></div>
    } 
}
```

In route file

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Switch} from 'react-router-dom;
export class RoutingClass extends React.Component{
    render(){
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    }
}
```